# showing prices of other group

Tags: price, group, switcher

I'm working on a reseller shop...

The customer=reseller should be able to switch the price views from

reseller price to final price and back.

One way would be to change the accountgroup_id temporarily but it MUST NOT be saved permanently.

How can I change the group temporarily or is there a better way?
The temporary group id is stored in the session.

And it must not have any effect to the order - the order price must be the reseller price.

Answer (score 0):

There seems no way just to store it in the session, I had to change the groupId of the user and remembering the real groupId in another attribute.
The groupId will be reset back when the customer logs out, logs in or goes to the one page checkout.

There will still be a problem when the Customer has more than one open, the group change and reset will affect all his sessions.

Comment: this has to do with the index table Magento uses for quickly showing prices. Because you can add prices for each customergroup and product it will expand very quickly, to maintain speed, Magento put this sort of data in flat index tables for quick look-ups.